# How to get random numbers OUT of Dieharder test suite?

Tags: ubuntu, math, cryptography, statistics

I've downloaded the [Dieharder tests](https://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php) using:

```
apt-get install dieharder
```

... on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The [dieharder man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dieharder.1.html) explains that to get random numbers OUT from one of the many Dieharder random generators you type (I think):

```
dieharder -g 041 -t 50 -o ./random_out.txt
```

But when I try that an many other variations I get nothing but the man page to STDOUT or even less.  The tests run on input and on the provided tests when selected.

But how do you get the original random numbers generated by the dieharder tests OUT and into a file?

Comment: This is a well-known test of a common Ubuntu utility whose documentation appears to be incorrect.  Also, this question has not been asked before.  Lastly, there are other questions out there about Dieharder usage and properties so the topic definitely gets attention here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual is wrong, -o seems to signal random numbers should be output but it does not take an option. If you give it a file name `-o foo` it causes an error causing the options to be displayed.

To write to a file you can use the option as DhruvPathak write. Another way is to combine `-o` with the `-f` option which specifies a filename.

```
dieharder -g 041 -t 50 -o -f foo.txt
```

writes 50 psudo-random numbers to the file foo.txt.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this variation:

```
dieharder -g 041 -d 1 -t 50 -o > random.txt
```